# enable/disable keystrokes if focus is on textfield and input

Tags: javascript, purejs-onepage-scroll

I am using [onepagescroll](https://github.com/peachananr/purejs-onepage-scroll/) on a simple portfolio page.  I wanted to add spacebar functionality and found the code in the plug-in to modify.

Now it scrolls with the spacebar, however after testing a contact form on the page I notice that none of the keys associated with the plug-in work while focus is on a textarea or input.

If I remove a case for a key, the textarea works as expected and I can move up/down/indent with space, so the problem is somewhere inside this code:

```
    _keydownHandler = function(e) {
    var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();

    if (!_hasClass(body, "disabled-onepage-scroll")) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 38:
                if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') moveUp(el)
                break;
            case 40:
                if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') moveDown(el)
                break;
            case 32:
                if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') moveDown(el)
                break;
            default: return;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(settings.keyboard == true) {
    document.onkeydown = _keydownHandler;
}
return false;
}
```

I have been trying to wrap my head around it but my knowledge of js is limited, the code seems to make sense as is.  Is there an error somewhere or do I need to write an else statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figured it out, will post the answer in case this comes up for anyone else.

```
if (!_hasClass(body, "disabled-onepage-scroll")) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38:
            if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') moveUp(el)
            break;
        case 40:
            if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') moveDown(el)
            break;
        case 32:
            if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') moveDown(el)
            break;
        default: return;
    } 
return true;  //add this
}
return false;
```